# cant set cookie inside private function

Tags: laravel, cookies

here is my routes

```
Route::get('/cookie/{set?}', 'SomeController@cookie');
Route::get('/cookie/set/public', 'SomeController@set_cookie_public');
```

here are my functions

```
function cookie(Request $request , $set = 0 ){

    dump($request->cookie('xxx'));
    if($set == 1 )
        $this->set_cookie_private();
}

private  function set_cookie_private(){
    Cookie::queue('xxx', 'abc' , 8000000 );
}

function set_cookie_public(){
    Cookie::queue('xxx', 'abc' , 8000000 );
}
```

when i call this address

```
site.com/cookie/1
```

it should call `set_cookie_private`  function and set the cookie there but when i call

```
site.com/cookie
```

cookie is null

but when i call `set_cookie_public` by going to its url

```
site.com/cookie/set/public
```

and then head back to `site.com/cookie` it shows cookie been set

why is that ? it seems if i call a url over and over again even of parameters in the url change it still wont set the cookie

Comment: if you `dump($set)` are you getting the parameter value in your `cookie()` function?

Comment: @hdifen `$set` is just a flag to tell laravel to set the cookie it doesnt have important value

Comment: Yes, are you getting the expected value that you are passing in from your route parameter?

Comment: yes the value is 0 or 1

Comment: Can you confirm that when the `$set` value is set to `1` you are getting to `set_cookie_private()`?  Pretty much I don't have enough information to help you entirely so I just want to make sure the basics are covered.

Comment: @hdifen yes did dump some data inside `set_cookie_private` ... i believe it wont set becuz i refresh the same url

Comment: I wouldn't think that would be the case as it should still be making a request to the server. Are you returning a response in both functions? Since you are returning void I think the cookie might not end out getting set on the response.